# How to sort the items of one column of a table based on the values of another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, group-by, columnsorting

I am using MySQL with Sequel Pro Mac OS X.  I have a table that is shown in the below screen shot.

[screen shot of table in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XfTY.png)

How can I order the values of the "PIT_ID" column in chronological order as a function of the values of the "Date_ID" column of the same table?  In other words, I'd like each pitcher listed in the "PIT_ID" column to be grouped together and ordered by chronological date of each of his starts.  As the table looks now, each pitcher's starts are grouped together and they are ordered by the date of his starts but only as a function of the team he played against (i.e., as designated by the first three characters of column "GAME_ID").  So, using the first shown name in the "PIT_ID" column as an example, "aased001", there are 91 rows with that starter "aased001".  Each of those 91 rows reflects 91 different games he played in and contains unique data reflecting statistics for the game. Those 91 rows of data are only in chronological date order for each team he played against.  In this case they are in chronological order for Baltimore, but the date chronology starts all over again for the next team he played against, Boston, rather than the table showing pure chronological date order of his starts regardless of team (or not as a function of the team he played against).  In the table, I would like a given pitcher's starts to be grouped together by pitcher and ordered by pure chronological order of date independent of team he played against.

I hope that made sense.  Please ask for clarification.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

There is a PRIMARY KEY combination between PIT_ID and GAME_ID, although I'm not sure that is necessary--I'm not sure what that actually allows in practical terms.  Here is the code that I try and it will sort the PIT_ID by chronological date order but will not make the change to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log;
SELECT PIT_ID, DATE_ID
FROM starting_pitcher_game_log
ORDER BY PIT_ID,DATE_ID
```

Here is some sample data from the three columns referenced after I run the above query (but no change to the actual table):

```
PIT_ID      DATE_ID     GAME_ID
aased001    1977-07-26  BOS197707260
aased001    1977-07-31  CAL197707310
aased001    1977-08-06  OAK197708060
aased001    1977-08-11  BOS197708110
aased001    1977-08-16  BOS197708160
aased001    1977-08-21  KCA197708210
aased001    1977-08-26  BOS197708260
aased001    1977-08-31  BOS197708310
aased001    1977-09-05  TOR197709051
aased001    1977-09-10  BOS197709100
aased001    1977-09-16  BAL197709160
aased001    1977-09-22  DET197709220
aased001    1977-09-27  BOS197709271
aased001    1978-04-11  CAL197804110
```

Comment: Please post actual DDL (or at least the relevant columns and their types) and some actual sample data (not images) and the desired output from that data

Comment: ALTER TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log; I don't understand this statement

Comment: Perhaps ALTER TABLE is not the correct code for what I want to do.  My intention is to change the permanent table structure/contents to reflect the sorting principle shown and described above.  Namely that each pitcher's starts will be grouped together and shown in chronological order by the date of his start.  The way the table looks now (as shown in the screen shot), it does not look that way.  So, I'd like the table to look like the above three columns of sample data.

Comment: The following worked:  ALTER TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log ORDER BY PIT_ID, DATE_ID ASC; Thank you everyone for the support.